# polyglossia loads luatexbase

Tags: luatex, fontspec, polyglossia

This is a coding question (from a low-skill coder). Using `lualatex` compiler on Linux.
TeXlive 2022. Search did not provide useful results.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
% Uncomment to see difference:
%\RequirePackage{luatexbase}
%\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

Inspect the mwe.log file. Notice that `fontspec` by itself does not load `luatexbase`.
But file `polyglossia.sty` contains this code:

```
\sys_if_engine_luatex:T{
  \RequirePackage{luatexbase} % already included by fontspec, but needed here
  \RequireLuaModule{polyglossia}
}
```

Apparently, "already included by fontspec" is incorrect.
Or is there something I do not grasp?

How I discovered this: I have been playing around with code from various packages,
to see what they do. I came across `priority_in_callback` which is in `luatexbase`.
Interestingly, there are other references to `luatexbase` that work, even when
`luatexbase` is not loaded! That is a mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comment was true when written. But post 2015, most of luatexbase was renamed and recoded as ltluatex and included in to the format so fontspec does not need it. All the Lua parts of ltluatex are in a module still called `luatexbase` for compatibilty.

The current `luatexbase` package is re-written to mostly be `ltluatex` which is pre-loaded by the format, but defines a few extra functions for compatibility with the original version of the package.

Comment: Thanks. That was my guess, but I do not know enough about coding.